# How to sort the Servers window in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have several different parameter sets with which I like to be able to run my project on a tomcat server, and I've made separate server objects for all of them in Eclipse's "Servers" tab. The problem is that, when creating these, I didn't have the foresight to pre-arrange them in the right order, I've had to change the name of some, and some new servers appeared in the middle of the list instead of the end, so my servers tab looks kind of like this:

```
> [] myproject - workspace - DEVDB
> [] myproject - tomcat - QADB
> [] myproject - tomcat - DEVDB
> [] myproject - workspace - PRODDB
> [] myproject - workspace - QADB
> [] myproject - tomcat - PRODDB
```

I can't figure out any way to manually or automatically reorder the servers - clicking and dragging them doesn't change the order, and the right-click context menu doesn't provide a "sort", "move up", or "move down" option.

I would settle for just the `workspace` and `tomcat` trios being grouped together, with their respective names in the same order as each other (e.g. alphabetical order), so that I don't have to look as closely when I'm running one server or the other, but having them chaotically mixed is unpleasant.

**Is there any way to get this tab to reorder itself, or some way to do so manually?**

(my version of "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers" is 2021-03 (4.19.0))

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to open a feature request at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=WTP%20ServerTools&component=wst.server . With the control being a tree rather than a table, you'll only likely get an alphabetical sort added.

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to just rename the servers to match the order I want them in (by naming them 1.server A, 2. server B, 3. server C, ... (see screen shot)

[image]